# Cascading dropdown with Filemaker Pro Advanced with tables from SQL server

Tags: filemaker

I've watched a videos from filemaker and other ppl posting on youtube but I can get my head around this issue. How can I make a cascading dropdown fields on a filemaker form that the next one relates to the previous choise.

I have three simple SQL tables

**dbo.TPS_SiteNames**
ID (PK)
SiteName (nvarchar(50))

**dbo.TPS_Customers**
ID (PK)
SiteName (nvarchar(50))
CustomerName (nvarcar(500))

**dbo.TPS_CustomerProducts**
ID (PK)
FK_TPS_Customers (FK to Customers:ID)
ProductCode (nvarchar(50))
ProductDescription (nvarchar(500))

The idea is the first dropdown to show the list from SiteNames, then the second dropdown to show a list with Customers but ONLY for the chosen SiteName and last the third dropdown to show list with Products only for the selected Customer.

The first dropdown looks ok on my form, but then the second and the third shows nothing.
This is my relation set up under FileMaker Pro Advanced:
[image: Database Table Relations]

I also have created three value lists where the first one shows all the SiteNames from the first table. The second one should ideally show all the CustomerName where related with the first choice and then the third one needs to show all the ProductCodes that are related to the selected Customer.

Please see the images bellow:

[image: Value List: SiteNames]
[image: Value List: Customers]
[image: Value List: Products]

Comment: AFAICT, the problem is not with the value lists, but with the relationships.The |-- line terminator indicates that the field cannot be indexed - thus it cannot be used as a match field on the "other" side (the side being queried) of the relationship - see: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fworking-relationships-graph.html%23ww1156152

Comment: OK I saw what you mean, but as I am using data from SQL via external ODBC connection, what do I need to do in order to make this relations to work?

Comment: I don't know. It's not something you can do In Filemaker; you must make sure the external data source indexes those fields.